# move through object filled with objects

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

im getting data from a database via php and convert the php-array to javascript via:

`var dbarrayjs = <?php echo json_encode($dbarrayphp);?>;`

this way js outputs one object where every record of my database is an object itself. the records (one row of my database) consist of 2 strings.
One of the strings is a list of numbers, separated by "," and need to be changed to an array via string.split. The other string is a simple digit.
The meaning of this is to describe the predecessor of a tree-like system. The single digit string is a node and the multi-digit string contains all of its direct parent nodes. One special criteria is, that all parents need to be passed in order to confirm the child.

My need is a way to traverse through this system and check if i can reach every element in this tree or if there is one element that can not be reached because of bad predecessor choices. a simple example would be this:
[image: Example predecessor tree]

Edit: 21st March 2017 - i was looking for a topsort algorithm and did not knew it back then.

Comment: You have to provide some sample test data and some code you've tried so far.  A tip, write a recursive function to traverse through the list but keep in mind to ignore the object if it's already been process, or else you'll get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic algorithm in graph theory.  You have a *directed graph*: the connections go in only one direction.  If you have a given root node, the search is rather easy: do a full traversal of the root's tree (either depth-first or [breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)).  Then see whether you've hit all the nodes.

Your problem description is a bit vague: do you need only to detect whether there's a missing node?  Do you need to identify it?  Is there, indeed, only one missing node possible?  Depending on these details, your implementation's accounting might need to do a little more work.

For instance, if all you must do is to detect whether there is any missing node, simply count the nodes as you visit them in your search.  If the final count is less than the count of nodes in the data base, then you have some missing.

If you must identify the missing nodes, then you must keep track of which nodes you've visited.  Then you need another block of code to extract all nodes of the graph, reporting those that aren't in your "visited" list.